# Can modernizr load scripts asynchronously but execute them in order?

Tags: modernizr

I'm experimenting with Modernizer.load.

I have this:

```
Modernizr.load([
      {
         load  : ['/js/jquery-1.6.1.js', '/js/jquery.tools.min.js', '/js/myscript.js']
      }
      ]);
```

If I understand correctly, I can use code like this to load scripts asynchronously. However, can I then execute them in order? What if myscript.js requires the jquery object to be loaded first?

In the example in the modernizr documentation, load([]) can take a 'complete' property, the parameter of which can be a function that can load another script when everything else is done. However, if I use a function here to load my post-dependancy script, then it loads in serial. The docs specifically say that this can harm perfomance.

However, if I load everything asynchronously, I don't have any idea about the order in which they run. And of course, I need my dependancies to run first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use `Modernizr.load`, all the files you include via the embedded list/hash will be **loaded** asynchronously, but they’ll each be **executed** in the order that you put them in.

So, your example will load the files asynchronously but execute them in this order:

```
1: /js/jquery-1.6.1.js
2: /js/jquery.tools.min.js
3: /js/myscript.js`
```

You can simplify your example, by the way:

```
Modernizr.load(['/js/jquery-1.6.1.js', '/js/jquery.tools.min.js', '/js/myscript.js']);
```

For more details, see the [Modernizr.load() tutorial](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#load) in the Documentation, or check out [Yepnopejs.com](http://yepnopejs.com/) (which is what Modernizr.load() basically is, at this time).