# Modernizr load [A, B] seems to execute B before A, how is this possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modernizr, yepnope

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).load({ both: [a, b] }) seems to executes `b` before `a` but that's not how Modernizr is supposed to work? ["*yepnope.js [used by Modernizr] always executes things in the order they are listed*"](http://yepnopejs.com/)

Modernizr versions 2.5.3 and 2.6.2.

I'm loading [angular.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js) and [angular-sanitize.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular-sanitize.js) like so:

```
Modernizr.load({
  both: [
    cdnDir + 'angular.js',
    cdnDir + 'angular-sanitize.js',
    d.i.assetsUrlPathStart + 'debiki-dashbar.js'],
  complete: bootstrapAngular
})
```

However, infrequently, `angular-sanitize.js` dies because `angular` does not yet exist.

But isn't `Modernizr.load(both: [a, b, c])` guaranteed to execute a, b, c in order? What is happening...?

***Details:***

The error happens on an `angular.extend(...)` line in [angular-sanitize.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular-sanitize.js), the last line in this excerpt: (line 148)

```
// Elements that you can, intentionally, leave open (and which close themselves)
// http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#optional-tags
var optionalEndTagBlockElements = makeMap("colgroup,dd,dt,li,p,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,tr"),
    optionalEndTagInlineElements = makeMap("rp,rt"),
    optionalEndTagElements = angular.extend({}, optionalEndTagInlineElements, optionalEndTagBlockElements);
```

Here's the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined
>   ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular-sanitize.js:148

and Chrome's debugger shows that `window.angular` is indeed undefined — althought it's being used on the very last line in [angular.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js) (which is supposed to be executed first of all).

Chrome (version 24.0.1312.57) says that both angular.js and angualar-sanitize.js are loaded from the browser's cache.

---

Update: This more explicit rewrite really should work I think. But when run, it sometimes prints "Angular absent" and dies later on (when angular-sanitize.js runs)— although Angular "must" just have been created.

```
Modernizr.load({
  load: cdnDir + 'angular.js', // <-- creates `angular`
  complete: function(){
    if (typeof angular == 'undefined' || angular === null) {
      console.log('Angular absent.');  // <-- printed sometimes, and everything fails
    }
    Modernizr.load({
      load: cdnDir + 'angular-sanitize.js',
      complete: ...
      }
    });
  }
});
```

---

Someone marked this question as a duplicate of:  [Can modernizr load scripts asychronously but execute them in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673406/can-modernizr-load-scripts-asychronously-but-execute-them-in-order) — however, if you read this question carefully, you'll notice that this question itself actually already *includes* the *answer* to that other question (namely this: *"[...] always executes things in the order they are listed"* — that's the answer to the other question).  Instead, this question, is about why things does *not* work in the way they should, according to the docs.

Comment: I think modernizr load scrips in parallel. You can load your scripts like `{ load: script_1 }, { load: script_2 }` to see if this solves your problem... or load a script after the other has completed.

Comment: It *loads* them in parallel, but it's supposed to *execute* them in the order they're listed. I have tested your suggestion, i.e. `[{ load: a }, { load: b }]`, same result. I also tested: `[{ load: a, complete: function() { Modernizr.load({ load: b ...})}]`, same result: `b` apparently runs before `a` (but infrequently).

Comment: Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571644/yepnope-js-complete-handler-firing-but-script-not-available

Comment: Two perhaps related question, but for `callback` not `complete`:  1)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182805/yepnopejs-callback-triggered-before-tiny-js-file-is-fully-loaded  and 2)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584118/yepnope-key-value-pairs-not-executing-as-expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can modernizr load scripts asychronously but execute them in order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673406/can-modernizr-load-scripts-asychronously-but-execute-them-in-order)